# Tails behind IPCop

Tags: anonymity, tails

Are there any known unintended consequences (reduction in anonymity, etc.) when using a firewall (IPCop) between Tails and my ISP? (I don't think so, but...)

Unless I have misconfigured IpCop, I am allowing only HTTP and HTTPS from the LAN (Tails) to the WAN (ISP).